# Why is my Contributions tab missing from contact summary screens?

Tags: civicontribute

I've just become aware that an up to date installation is not showing the Contributions tab on contact summary screens.

I'm seeing no errors in the browser console, not anything in the CiviCRM log. The only thing I am aware of with respect to contributions is that a colleague recently made some changes to the Financial Types and Financial Accounts to better align with our accounting system (Quickbooks). Could that have caused this issue?

As far as I can see the contribution records are all there, just that I can't get access  them from the contact record.

Comment: I imagine you've checked, but just in case: CiviContribute extension and CiviContribute component are both enabled? There have been some issues with them being disabled in upgrades.

Comment: Also check your permissions particularly if you have access restricted by financial types

Answer (score 1):

What I failed to check was the fact that a colleague had used the Contact Layout Editor to tweak the setup of the contact summary screen, and had removed the tab from the layout. The joys of team-working and poor documentation. Doh!